# Do timestamps returned from EC2 Cloudwatch represent the beginning or end of the period?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

When I query the Cloudwatch API for CPUUtilization for my EC2 instances, each returned datapoint has a "Timestamp" property.  Does this timestamp represent the beginning, middle, or end of the aggregation period for this datapoint?

For instance, if I'm querying with a 5 minute period, does a datapoint with the timestamp 10:00 am represent the CPU average between 9:55 am - 10:00 am, or 10:00 am - 10:05 am?

I checked the documentation for the Datapoint type (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_Datapoint.html) and all it says is that the Timestamp is "The time stamp used for the data point."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Timestamp is the start of the range. In your example, datapoint with the timestamp of 10:00am will cover 10:00am - 10:05am.

I'm not sure if this is mentioned there, but [CloudWatch Concepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html) page is a good read along side the API docs.

Comment: I asked AWS support as well and they confirmed this is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

From [Amazon CloudWatch Concepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html):

> When statistics are aggregated over a period of time, they are stamped
>   with the time corresponding to the beginning of the period. For
>   example, data aggregated from 7:00pm to 8:00pm is stamped as 7:00pm.